# Create Firebase notification with page in foreground/focus

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

With Firebase Cloud Messaging (for web), how can I generate the notification that appears when the webpage is closed or in the background, but when I'm actually focused on the webpage?

It's my understanding that `messaging.onMessage(...)` is where I handle incoming messages when the page is in focus, but I can't seem to find documentation on how I could still create the notification pop-ups as though the page were in the background.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: You will need to set up a `manifest.json` and `firebase-messaging-sw.js` for that. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/receive#handle_messages_when_your_web_app_is_in_the_background

Comment: I have both of those files setup. In the .js file, I have this function which creates a notification when my page is in the background:
`    messaging.setBackgroundMessageHandler(function(payload) {
  console.log('[firebase-messaging-sw.js] Received background message ', payload);
  // Customize notification here
  const notificationTitle = 'Coffee Train!';
  const notificationOptions = {
    body: 'All aboard!',
    icon: 'coffee-train-icon-red-50.png'
  };

  return self.registration.showNotification(notificationTitle,
      notificationOptions);
});`

Comment: Sorry, apparently I can't find a good way to format code in a comment... the main point is that the message.setBackgroundMessageHandler function seems to handle creating a notification with the self.registration.showNotification function, but I can't seem to figure out how to do the same in the messaging.onMessage function that executes when my webpage is in focus and receives a message.

Comment: I don't think you can show the same type of notification bubble when the web page is displaying. Since the app is already visible to the user, you're expected to handle that differently: for example by highlighting the relevant section of the web page.

Comment: Bummer, that's too bad. The main reason I had wanted to have the notification bubble appear was to handle the situation of a user having my webpage open as the active tab, but is working on a different application (like Excel or something) and may be completely coving the browser window with the other application window. When I test this scenario, my webpage is catching the notification, but it's handled in the foreground on the page, and not by the background service worker. Is there some other function that can handle this sort of scenario?

Comment: I've been wondering about that scenario too: web notifications feel different from native mobile notifications, since in desktop the browser often takes just a tiny part of the screen and it's easy to miss the notification. I haven't looked for a way to show notifications from within the page itself yet. So it may exist, I just haven't seen it.

Comment: How about playing a unique sound in that case?

Answer (score 33):

handle incoming messges by Notification API

```
messaging.onMessage(function(payload) {
    const notificationTitle = payload.notification.title;
    const notificationOptions = {
        body: payload.notification.body,
        icon: payload.notification.icon,        
    };

    if (!("Notification" in window)) {
        console.log("This browser does not support system notifications");
    }
    // Let's check whether notification permissions have already been granted
    else if (Notification.permission === "granted") {
        // If it's okay let's create a notification
        var notification = new Notification(notificationTitle,notificationOptions);
        notification.onclick = function(event) {
            event.preventDefault(); // prevent the browser from focusing the Notification's tab
            window.open(payload.notification.click_action , '_blank');
            notification.close();
        }
    }
});
```

---

### Notification is deprecated.

send message to service worker

---

```
   messaging.onMessage(function(payload) {
        local_registration.active.postMessage(payload);
     }
```

receive message and show push from sw.js

```
self.addEventListener('notificationclick', function(event) {
console.log('[firebase-messaging-sw.js] Received notificationclick event ', event);

var click_action = event.notification.data;
event.notification.close();
// This looks to see if the current is already open and
// focuses if it is
event.waitUntil(clients.matchAll({
    type: "window"
}).then(function(clientList) {
    for (var i = 0; i < clientList.length; i++) {
        var client = clientList[i];
        if (client.url == click_action  && 'focus' in client)
            return client.focus();
    }
    if (clients.openWindow)
        return clients.openWindow(click_action);
    }));

});
const showMessage = function(payload){
    console.log('showMessage', payload);
    const notificationTitle = payload.data.title;
    const notificationOptions = {
        body: payload.data.body,
        icon: payload.data.icon,
        image: payload.data.image,
        click_action: payload.data.click_action,
        data:payload.data.click_action
    };  


  return self.registration.showNotification(notificationTitle,notificationOptions); 
}   
messaging.setBackgroundMessageHandler(showMessage);

self.addEventListener('message', function (evt) {     
  console.log("self",self);
  showMessage( evt.data );
})
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this will not work for Android when app is in foreground.
Notification is deprecated.

Answer (score 13):

Since Notification is deprecated in Android, you should use Firebase serviceWorker registration to show the notification.

As of Feb 2020, it looks like Firebase registers its serviceWorker with the '/firebase-cloud-messaging-push-scope' scope (as can be seen in chrome devtools -> Application -> Service Workers)

To use that, you can do:

```
messaging.onMessage(function(payload) {
    console.log("onMessage: ", payload);
    navigator.serviceWorker.getRegistration('/firebase-cloud-messaging-push-scope').then(registration => {
        registration.showNotification(
            payload.notification.title,
            payload.notification
        )
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

More clean approach would be:

```
messaging.onMessage(payload => {
  const {title, ...options} = payload.notification;
  navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then(registration => {
    registration.showNotification(title, options);
  });
});
```

Comment: Where should I write this code. Should I write this in the serviceworker  like written for background method?

Comment: No, it should be handled by browser, after `firebase.initializeApp(FCM_CONFIG); const messaging = firebase.messaging();`

Comment: this didn't work for me in Chrome. The [getRegistration approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60247902/862225) worked fine though