# Firebase messaging & ReactJS, when website in foreground, push notification not being received

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using ReactJS & Firebase Messaging. I currently have a working solution if the website is in background, I get the notification alert. However, when it's in the foreground, I don't even seem to be receiving the message?

I have found postings that talk about the same issue,but their solutions aren't working for me, as I don't even receive the message, never mind how I display it. Here are other postings.

[Web foreground push notification is not popping up integrated using Firebase in Reactjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60220555/web-foreground-push-notification-is-not-popping-up-integrated-using-firebase-in)

[Create Firebase notification with page in foreground/focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40411059/create-firebase-notification-with-page-in-foreground-focus)

Below is my App.js file, which sets up the messaging and uses the messaging.onMessage() method, I've revmoved everything, and just want it to write to the console, but it never gets fired when I send a message to it.

What am I missing?

```
import React,{useState} from 'react';
import { ToastContainer } from 'react-toastify';
import Router from './components/Router';
import Auth from './containers/Auth';
import Form from './containers/Form';
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
import {getToken} from './clients/firebase';
import DashboardPage from './containers/Dashboard';
import { ROUTES } from './constants';


function App() {
  const [isTokenFound, setTokenFound] = useState(false);
  const [notification, setNotification] = useState({title: '', body: ''});
  getToken(setTokenFound); 

  const messaging = firebase.messaging();
  
  messaging.onMessage(payload => {
    console.log('received');
  });

  return (<>
      <Router>
        <Auth path={ROUTES.AUTH.CHILDREN} />
        <DashboardPage path={ROUTES.DASHBOARD.CHILDREN} />
        <Form path={ROUTES.FORMS.CHILDREN} />
      </Router>
      <ToastContainer />
 </> );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Hey Mike, have you found the solution?

Comment: No, I ended up removing web notifications in the app, and went with a different approach.