# Using firebase messaging, console log shows that payload is received, but no chrome notification pop up is shown

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have set up the firebase.messaging().onMessage() and firebase-messaging-sw.js as per documentation.

In the `index` file,

```
// Your web app's Firebase configuration
// For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: 'XX',
  authDomain: 'XX',
  projectId: 'XX',
  storageBucket: 'XX',
  messagingSenderId: 'XX',
  appId: '1:XX:XX',
  measurementId: 'G-XXX',
};

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

const messaging = firebase.messaging();

messaging
  .requestPermission()
  .then(function () {
    console.log('have permission');
    return messaging.getToken();
  })
  .then(function (token) {
    console.log('have permission', token);
  })
  .catch(function (err) {
    console.log('no permission', err);
  });

messaging.onMessage((payload) => {
  console.log('Message received. ', payload);
  // Update the UI to include the received message.
    navigator.serviceWorker.getRegistration('/firebase-cloud-messaging-push-scope').then(registration => {
        registration.showNotification(
            payload.notification.title,
            payload.notification
        )
    });
});
```

In the  `firebase-messaging-sw.js` file:

```
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.5.0/firebase-app.js');
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.5.0/firebase-messaging.js');

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: 'xx-xx',
  authDomain: 'xx-xx.firebaseapp.com',
  projectId: 'xx-assistant',
  storageBucket: 'xx-xx.appspot.com',
  messagingSenderId: 'xx',
  appId: '1:xx:xxx',
  measurementId: 'G-xx',
};

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

const messaging = firebase.messaging();

messaging.setBackgroundMessageHandler(function (payload) {
  console.log(
    '[firebase-messaging-sw.js] Received background message ',
    payload
  );
  // Customize notification here
  const notificationTitle = payload.notification.title;
  const notificationOptions = {
    body: payload.notification.body,
    icon: payload.notification.icon,
    image: payload.notification.image,
    click_action: payload.notification.click_action,
  };

  return self.registration.showNotification(
    notificationTitle,
    notificationOptions
  );
});
```

When I send a payload from the firebase console, I get the response in the front end and console.log outputs-

```
data: {notification: "{\"icon\":\"app.xxx.com\\/images\\/logo\",\"title\":\"New notification\",\"body\":\"Tthis is body\"}"}
from: "xxxxx"
```

But I don't see the notification pop that is generated by chrome.
As I understand, it should just show up if firebase.messaging().onMessage() or onBackgroundMessage is fired, but it is not.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

My system-level permissions for notification were disabled.
After enabling the notification permissions, it worked without issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement the notification pop-up when you receive a notification in the foreground. It won't show up automatically.

Here's a code snippet from [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40411059/create-firebase-notification-with-page-in-foreground-focus) showing how to do this:

```js
messaging.onMessage(function(payload) {
    console.log("onMessage: ", payload);
    navigator.serviceWorker.getRegistration('/firebase-cloud-messaging-push-scope').then(registration => {
        registration.showNotification(
            payload.notification.title,
            payload.notification
        )
    });
});
```

Comment: does this apply to app in background as well?

Comment: Even for foreground notification, this does not work. I can still see in the console log that notification payload is received, but no pop up shown. I have updated the code with all the code.

Comment: The issue was in the system permissions.